# How to check that some value is in the pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
In [12]: df.pat
Out[12]: 
0    foo
1    bar
Name: pat, dtype: object

In [14]: 'bar' in df.pat
Out[14]: False
```

Why is the result False? How can I check that 'cronus' is in the column?

Comment: You need to check its values `'bar' in df.pat.values`

Comment: 3 ways -- `'bar' in df.pat.values` or `df.pat.isin(['bar']).any()` or `(df.pat == 'bar').any()`